# Split File Path into Components in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, split, filepath

Is there a framework or a library that I could use to split a file path into its components in iPhone SDK? I know I could code it myself, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`-[NSString pathComponents]` is made exactly for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but [`NSFileManager`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s [`-subpathsAtPath`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/subpathsAtPath:) method sounds like what you want to do. It splits up the components of a path into an `NSArray`.

**EDIT**: Actually, I might have misunderstood the documentation. Sorry if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just split at the character `/`; the [relevant documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Strings/Articles/ManipulatingPaths.html) says that "NSString represents paths generically with ‘/’ as the path separator and ‘.’ as the extension separator." So a simple

```
NSArray *components = [pathString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
```

should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

[pathForResource? without using extension (Iphone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984572/pathforresource-without-using-extension-iphone)

One of the answers to this question provides the necessary code.  Just the question is badly formulated.